# Renaming a content type during migration

Tags: 8, migrations

I am migrating a Drupal 6 site to Drupal 8. On the Drupal 6 site I have a content type called *book_page* but would like it be called *faq* on the new site.

I set the `default_bundle` to faq in my yml file but it still migrates as book_page.

Here is my yml file:

```
uuid: a67dbd6f-416c-44c0-9698-05ec3bb3c5a9
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
id: upgrade_d6_node_book_page
migration_tags:
  - 'Drupal 6'
migration_group: d6_migrate_group
label: 'Nodes (book_page)'
source:
  plugin: d6_node
  node_type: book_page
process:
  nid: tnid
  vid: vid
  langcode:
    plugin: default_value
    source: language
    default_value: und
  title: title
  uid: node_uid
  status: status
  created: created
  changed: changed
  promote: promote
  sticky: sticky
  body/format:
    plugin: migration
    migration: upgrade_d6_filter_format
    source: format
  body/value: body
  body/summary: teaser
  revision_uid: revision_uid
  revision_log: log
  revision_timestamp: timestamp
  field_image:
    plugin: d6_cck_file
    source: field_image
  field_upload_files:
    plugin: d6_cck_file
    source: field_upload_files
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
  default_bundle: faq
migration_dependencies:
  required:
    - upgrade_d6_user
    - upgrade_d6_node_type
    - upgrade_d6_node_settings
    - upgrade_d6_filter_format
  optional:
    - upgrade_d6_field_instance_widget_settings
    - upgrade_d6_field_formatter_settings
    - upgrade_d6_upload_field_instance
```

Anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

**Update:**

I have also tried adding the following under process under each of my node yml files?:

```
type:
  plugin: default_value
  value: faq
```

I wonder if the All node types are created in ....node_type.yml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've figured out, modifying the d6_node-based migration affects how the *content* of a given node type is migrated, but does not affect how the actual node type itself is migrated - that is done in d6_node_type. To rename the types themselves in migration, while you could modify the source query as you did, it's simpler to modify the .yml to remap values.
In upgrade_d6_node_type.yml,  you can replace

```
process:
  type: type
  name: name
```

with

```
process:
  type:
    plugin: static_map
    bypass: true
    source: type
    map:
      story: post
      book_page: faq
  name:
    plugin: static_map
    bypass: true
    source: name
    map:
      story: post
      'Book Page': Faq
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks like a better way than I did.  Any simple way to exclude content types as well from being created?

Comment: @albertski: Removing ```bypass: true``` from the type mapping should skip any node types not explicitly mapped.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens - Afraid I've never been - maybe someday!

Comment: Does anyone know what the key "story" refers to? Is that something from the OP that isn't there anymore, or a Drupal thing? I don't see mentioned it anywhere on https://www.drupalmigrate.org/plugin/process/staticmap or the OP, so not sure where it came from and if I need it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to perform this by creating a custom module and adding a custom source plugin to modify the query.

*custom_migration/src/Plugin/migrate/source/d6/CustomNodeType.php*

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom_migration\Plugin\migrate\source\d6;

use Drupal\node\Plugin\migrate\source\d6\NodeType;

/**
 * Drupal 6 Node types source from database.
 *
 * @MigrateSource(
 *   id = "custom_node_type"
 * )
 */
class CustomNodeType extends NodeType {
  /**
   * Override the query() method, and provide a custom query that selects just
   * the node types you want.
   */
  public function query() {
    // Our custom query returns only the node types we want and renames them.
    $query = $this->select('node_type', 't');
    $query->fields('t', array(
        'module',
        'description',
        'help',
        'title_label',
        'has_body',
        'body_label',
        'min_word_count',
        'custom',
        'modified',
        'locked',
        'orig_type',
      ));

    // Rename content types.
    $query->addExpression("
      CASE
        WHEN t.type = 'story' THEN 'post'
        WHEN t.type = 'book_page' THEN 'faq'
        ELSE t.type
      END
    ", 'type');

    // Rename content type names.
    $query->addExpression("
      CASE
        WHEN t.name = 'Book Page' THEN 'Faq'
        WHEN t.name = 'Story' THEN 'Story'
        ELSE t.name
      END
    ", 'name');

    // Exclude content types you don't want to migrate.
    $query->condition('t.type', array('forum', 'program', 'show', 'webform', 'homepage_slide'), 'NOT IN');
    $query->orderBy('t.type');

    return $query;
  }
}
```